# Sharepoint 2010 SPD Workflow Email SharePoint Group specified in Association Form?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, workflow-variable

Trying to do something, that I swear I've done before, and *I think* definitely should be possible, but wondering if I am missing something here.

I am using SPD2010 to create a custom Reusable workflow in a "Dev" farm.  The idea will be to export this and import to other "farms" as a Sandbox Solution.  As a result, I need to limit the "hard coding" of users/groups that I use.

My workflow will to start, just do something simple - sent an email to a set of users contained in a SharePoint Group.  The SharePoint Group set of users will be specified in an association form when the list is attached to the workflow by way of a "Person or Group" Parameter.

The association data parameter (i.e. the SP Group) should be used to specify the "To" line of the email activity.  I've tried setting this up a number of ways, including specifying the "Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimited" when specifying the lookup for the "To" field.  Nothing seems to work.  For many, I get errors similar to: "Coercion warning: user or group does not have a valid e-mail address." logged to workflow history.

I have ensured that the SPGroup is configured to allow "Everyone" to view the memberships and have ensured that the SPGroup has Read access to the site.

I am using Windows Claims for authentication - if that matters.

Am I missing something?  How do I configure an Association Form parameter of type "Users or Groups" and retrieve the email addresses to send notification emails?

***** UPDATE ******
I setup a workflow with email activity as described above, but in addition I specified the SharePoint Group directly in the CC line.  I compared the XOML.  Here goes:

```
<!-- binding from Association Form parameter -->
<ns0:ClearArrayListActivity x:Name="ID51" ReturnValue="{x:Null}" />
<ns0:CoerceStringActivity x:Name="ID53" __Context="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__context}" CoercionFunction="MultiEmailAddressSemicolon">
 <ns0:CoerceStringActivity.Value>
   <ActivityBind Name="ROOT" Path="MonitoringGroup" />
 </ns0:CoerceStringActivity.Value>
</ns0:CoerceStringActivity>
<ns0:AddToArrayListActivity x:Name="ID52" ReturnValue="{ActivityBind ID51,Path=ReturnValue}" Value="{ActivityBind ID53,Path=ReturnValue}" /><ns0:EmailActivity x:Name="ID4" __Context="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__context}" To="{ActivityBind ID51,Path=ReturnValue}" Subject="Group Parmater" BCC="{x:Null}" CC="{x:Null}" Body="blah 1" />

<!-- here is the binding of a group directly to the CC field -->
<ns0:ClearArrayListActivity x:Name="ID49" ReturnValue="{x:Null}" />
<ns0:AddToArrayListActivity x:Name="ID50" ReturnValue="{ActivityBind ID49,Path=ReturnValue}" Value="BCR Monitors" />
<ns0:EmailActivity x:Name="ID48" __Context="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__context}" To="{ActivityBind ID49,Path=ReturnValue}" Subject="directly to group (no parameter)" BCC="{x:Null}" CC="{x:Null}" Body="blah 2" />
```

Note that the extraction of the association parameter utilizes a CoerceStringActivity, which is then bound to the AddToArrayListActivity (looking at the ID and bindings specified).  However, when adding an SPGroup directly to the email CC field, not such CoerceStringActivity is used.

After looking at the code behind these activities, I am not seeing a way to extract all members of a SPGroup and bind them to the To field. Am I missing something???

Comment: Have you checked with your user/group's "Settings" page? Do they have email address listed on the page?

Comment: It's a SharePoint Group, the only email address I see on a SP Group Settings page is for managing access requests.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I had same problem, "Display name,Semicolon Delimited" works for me.